# Add a json document with mlab (mongodb in heroku) with multiple objects

Tags: json, mongodb, heroku

I am trying to import a JSON file to my mongoldb in heroku by using the 'Add document' button. When I only insert one object, everything is working accordingly. However, if I try to add multiple objects in the same JSON the site returns to the homepage without any result. The JSON looks like this:

```
[
{"flightNo":"t010118CND11111112","STD": {"$date": "2018-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"}}, 

{"flightNo":"t010118CND11121112","STD": {"$date": "2018-01-01T14:00:00.000Z"}}
]
```

Isn't it possible to import a large file containing multiple objects? If not, is there any other easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) to import JSON:

```
mongoimport -h ds123.mlab.com:123 -d mydb -c mycoll -u myuser -p "my password" --file "C:\Users\me\file.json" --jsonArray
```

The JSON files that MongoDB works with are usually formatted like this:

```
{"flightNo":"t010118CND11111112","STD": {"$date": "2018-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"}}
{"flightNo":"t010118CND11121112","STD": {"$date": "2018-01-01T14:00:00.000Z"}}
```

Note the lack of `[]` and comma. The `--jsonArray` parameter allows you to use ordinary JSON arrays:

```
[
  {"flightNo":"t010118CND11111112","STD": {"$date": "2018-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"}},
  {"flightNo":"t010118CND11121112","STD": {"$date": "2018-01-01T14:00:00.000Z"}}
]
```

Comment: I am trying this at the moment, but I get the following error: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed. I inserted the password from mongoDB, but I am not sure if that is the right one. Can't find another one though.

Comment: @SvenCozijn It should be the username and password that you use to connect to the database. If you use the mlab addon then you'll probably find it in the `MONGODB_URI` environment variable, which you can find with `heroku config:get MONGODB_URI` (and probably on the dashboard too).

Comment: It seems that the User that is created with mDB automatically does not come with a password. I created another user with my own UN and PW and that solved the problem.